# How do you exclude with two different conditions

Tags: sql

Wonder if anyone would know how to do this?

Basically I only need to return results where the Type equals 'I'  so I deleted the line ----AND PatientType = 'I' ----which works like a charm, but then I find out that I have some records with same MRN that contain both types of of "I' and "O". If they had a "O" then I can't count their "I". Now that means I have to delete the ones that meet that condition.  Yes you guessed it I am stuck again.  LOL

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
       p.id, 
       v.PatientID,
       p.firstname, 
       p.lastname, 
       p.dob, 
       p.mrn, 
       s.SmokeStatus,  
       v.VisitNo, 
       s.VisitID,
       v.ID,
   v.AdmitedDate

   FROM
       tblPatient p 
       JOIN tblPatientVisit v ON p.id = v.PatientID
       JOIN tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder s ON v.id = s.VisitID
   WHERE 
       isdate(p.DOB) = 1 
       AND CONVERT(date,p.DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
       AND isdate(v.AdmitedDate) = 1 
       AND CONVERT(date,v.AdmitedDate) > '06/16/2013 00:00' 

   AND v.PatientType = 'I'
   AND s.TobaccoType = 'Cigarettes' OR s.TobaccoType='Cigars' or s.TobaccoType='Pipes'
   AND v.PatientType !='O'
   AND v.PatientType !='2'
   AND v.PatientType = 'I'

   order by MRN
```

Answer (score 2):

add brackets, because you have a problem of operator precedence between OR and AND.

```
AND (s.TobaccoType = 'Cigarettes' OR s.TobaccoType='Cigars' or s.TobaccoType='Pipes')
```

or better, `IN` clause

```
AND s.TobaccoType IN ('Cigarettes', 'Cigars', 'Pipes')
```

Then, add a `NOT EXISTS` clause (if I understand well) to exclude the patients with "an O in any visit"

```
AND NOT EXISTS (select null from
                tblPatientVisit 
                where PatientId = p.id
                and PatientType = 'O')
```

so the entire query should be (not sure where the `v.PatientType != '2'` should go)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       p.id, 
       v.PatientID,
       p.firstname, 
       p.lastname, 
       p.dob, 
       p.mrn, 
       s.SmokeStatus,  
       v.VisitNo, 
       s.VisitID,
       v.ID,
       v.AdmitedDate

   FROM
       tblPatient p 
       JOIN tblPatientVisit v ON p.id = v.PatientID
       JOIN tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder s ON v.id = s.VisitID
   WHERE 
       isdate(p.DOB) = 1 
       AND CONVERT(date,p.DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
       AND isdate(v.AdmitedDate) = 1 
       AND CONVERT(date,v.AdmitedDate) > '06/16/2013 00:00' 
       AND v.PatientType = 'I'
       AND v.PatientType !='2'
       AND s.TobaccoType IN ('Cigarettes', 'Cigars', 'Pipes')
       AND NOT EXISTS (select null from
                    tblPatientVisit 
                    where PatientId = p.id
                    and PatientType = 'O')
```

Comment: @user3093389 sorry, some mistakes, now this should be alright.